# Django store the original value of a field

Tags: django, history, baseline

I am a newbie with Django trying to create a dashboard application reporting on some key milestone dates. I want to be able to track how the key dates are changing. For example:If the kick off date has been changed 5 times I want to be able to report 1. the first date entered, 2. Current date, 3. The date before the last update.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[django]+%22versioning%22

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. But for the logic you have asked one thing we can do is to make a model in which the edited dates and user will be fields. Use user as foreign key of your User model. I will just give an example model.

```
class Dates(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    date = models.DateField()
```

This is a very basic method which i am saying. This is a bit complex and you will have to check if the field has changed five times and all.

For a better answer please make the question clear.